# I am getting the error "Cannot use import statement outside a module" when I run my React Razzle app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap, razzle

Razzle is a server side rendering framework.

Here is the error:

```
/home/ajay/Ajay Nagotha/Projects/react-ssr-demo/luma-ssr/node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Container.js:1
import classNames from 'classnames';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: I wonder if searching for "Cannot use import statement outside a module" on Stack Overflow will give you the answer.

Comment: You can add { "type": "module" } in package.json to resolve this error, but you will likely run into other errors when trying to use modules that are not ES modules. You will need to use Bable or use all ES modules in your project.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Visual Studio Code and let it automatically add the imports, it can use the incorrect path.

When I ran into this in my Typescript project, I had Code do the import, which creates the code

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Container';
```

The correct code doesn't have the esm path and should be

```
import Container from 'react-boostrap/Container';
```